# Flink, how to deserialize protobuf using ProtobufSerializer?

Tags: protocol-buffers, apache-flink

I need to consume kafka via flink, unfortunately, the kafka message is using protobuf in serde, totally no idea how to deal with it, here is the code from internet, but I'm not able to make it work.

```
...    
import com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException;
import com.twitter.chill.protobuf.ProtobufSerializer;

public class Protobuf2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputTopic = "zz";
        String consumerGroup = "foobar";
        String address = "localhost:9092";
        StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        environment.getConfig().registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(ExchangeMessage.Order.class, ProtobufSerializer.class);

        FlinkKafkaConsumer<ExchangeMessage.Order> flinkKafkaConsumer = createStringConsumerForTopic(inputTopic, address,
                consumerGroup);
        DataStream<ExchangeMessage.Order> input = environment.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer);

        input.map(order ->
            {
                System.out.println("foooooooo, " + order.getOid());
                return order;
            });

        environment.execute("kafka02");
    }

    public static FlinkKafkaConsumer<ExchangeMessage.Order> createStringConsumerForTopic(String topic,
            String kafkaAddress, String kafkaGroup) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaAddress);
        props.setProperty("group.id", kafkaGroup);
        FlinkKafkaConsumer<ExchangeMessage.Order> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(topic,
                new OrderSerDeSchema(), props);
        return consumer;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    static class OrderSerDeSchema
            implements DeserializationSchema<ExchangeMessage.Order>, SerializationSchema<ExchangeMessage.Order> {

        @Override
        public ExchangeMessage.Order deserialize(byte[] message) throws IOException {
            ExchangeMessage.Order order = null;
            try {
                order = ExchangeMessage.Order.parseFrom(message);
            } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return order;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEndOfStream(ExchangeMessage.Order nextElement) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public TypeInformation<ExchangeMessage.Order> getProducedType() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] serialize(ExchangeMessage.Order element) {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    }

}
```

This doesn't work, it gives NPE:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:577)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:554)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:534)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:718)
    at ......
```

Anyone know what am I doing wrong here? Is it the only way to deser the protobuf -- to use twitter ProtobufSerializer? Or there's another way to go?

Answer (score 0):

add dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
    <artifactId>chill-protobuf</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and add this in your code

```
env.getConfig().registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(MockMessageProto.MockMessage.class, ProtobufSerializer.class);
```

maybe you will meet version conflict, change chill-protobuf version to fix it

Comment: change MockMessageProto.MockMessage.class to your protobuf class